# How to play multiple html5 audio files in iOS?

Tags: ios, html, audio

Let's say I have two audio files. I hooked them up with my javascript.

```
var audio1 = new Audio();
audio1.src = 'file1';
audio1.load();

var audio2 = new Audio();
audio2.src = 'file2';
audio2.load();
```

when I play audio1 then play audio2, mobile safari (ios) stops audio1 then plays audio2. It only happens with ios safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this is a design decision from Apple, it'S not possible to play more than one audio file.

Comment: crazy , i just use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194898/html5-audio-multiple-play/35459153#35459153

I can play as much as I want audio files. I just check now , background music works with click sounds on iOS mini ipad.

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing on this recently.  The short answer is as stated before, it doesn't work.  I tried working with mp3,m4a(aac I purchased on itunes),mp4 and aif, so file format has no bearing on iOS safari's ability to play more than one stream at a time.

I have currently "solved" the issue in my web app by assigning priorities to sounds in the app so it can intelligently interrupt or ignore requests to play a sound file.  Maybe you can try something similar.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to use server-side utility like [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to mix multiple audio files into one. It is not equivalent to playing multiple audio files at random position but depending on your needs it can be a solution.