# Audio and Video not consistantly failing in Sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I'm pretty new to Sencha touch 2, but I'm using it and xcode to upload the image onto an ipad.  I have audio that plays on the home screen, and once select a certain tab, the video is supposed to run and the audio is supposed to stop.  However, when the audio works on the home screen, I can't play the video, and when the video works, there's no audio.  I'm not quite sure what to do because which one fails varies across each run through, regardless of whether or not I've changed the code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785022/how-to-play-multiple-html5-audio-files-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apple limitation which makes it impossible to play more than one audio source at a time. This may also be the case for video+audio as well.

It's a performance issue, because the hardware can only decode one compressed file and decoding it with cpu makes the whole os too slow.

[Apple says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html):

> Audio format is critical when you play sounds simultaneously on iPhone
>   or iPod touch. This is because playback of certain compressed formats
>   in iOS employs an efficient hardware codec. Only a single instance of
>   one of the following formats can play on the device at a time:
>
> - AAC
> - ALAC (Apple Lossless)
> - MP3