# Play the same HTML5 audio in parallel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

The usual way of creating an audio player in JavaScript

```
var a = new Audio();
a.src = "test.mp3";
```

assumes the audio data is owned by the `Audio` object. What is the proper way to load audio data separately, and then create audio players which would play that existing data? One use-case is when you want to play the same sound simultaneously by multiple players, e.g. to create an echo effect. I would assume that to create another player using same data one can just do

```
var b = new Audio();
b.src = a.src;
```

but I wonder whether this is the best way to do it... and if it is, whether one would have to wait for `loadeddata`/`canplaythrough` events on `b` given those events had already fired on `a`.

Answer (score 5):

Since Audio is a regular DOM element you can use cloneNode() method to create and play the same sound.

```
// Create your audio and clone
var myAudio = new Audio('my.mp3');
var myClonedAudio = myAudio.cloneNode();

// Play them simultaneously
myAudio.play();
myClonedAudio.play();
```

Answer (score -1):

For playing multiple sounds at once you have to need to make 2 audio objects. Otherwise you can play the sound after the "ended" event like:

```
obj.addEventListener('ended', function() 
{
    obj.play();
}.bind(this, obj), false);
```

If you want multiple sounds at once, use a class for playing sounds, or music - which supports multiple channels.

Oh yes, to can play the sound, dont forget to add it, to the body:

```
var audioTag     = new Audio('');
document.body.appendChild(audioTag);
audioTag.src    =  name;
```

If you want such an audio-class, ask me (comment ;)

Comment: Why would one need to add an `Audio` object to body?

Comment: Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194898/html5-audio-multiple-play/35459153#35459153